# How can I send a Email with attachment via Outlook on MacOS from the command line

Tags: macos, email, outlook, email-attachments

I want to send an Excel workbook as a email attachment on on automated basis from the Command line of MacOS via Outlook, has to be via Outlook to get through all the required authentication.

I am already successfully creating the email with this command: `/usr/bin/open -b com.microsoft.outlook 'mailto:me@example.com?subject=reports&body=Please find attached reports'` but I cannot figure out how to pass an argument to attach a file

Comment: I'm not particularly attached to using "mailto" if another method exists, I see the Windows version of Outlook has a /a option to compose a mail with attachments but I cannot determine if it exists for MacOS -a didn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

`mailto` protocols does not support attachments. You can only do `to` (the default `mailto` parameter), `cc`, `bcc`, `subject`, `body`. No attachments or HTML body.

Answer (score 0):

The [mailto protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa767737(v=vs.85)) opens a client's e-mail system and begins a new email message. The optional parameters can be one of the following strings:

- subject -
  Text to appear in the subject line of the message.
- body -
  Text to appear in the body of the message.
- CC -
  Addresses to be included in the "cc" (carbon copy) section of the message.
- BCC -
  Addresses to be included in the "bcc" (blind carbon copy) section of the message.

There is no way to specify any attachments.

For more information on the mailto protocol, see [RFC2368: The mailto URL scheme](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=203480)